# Android studio doesn't catch breakpoint after switching to other apps

Tags: android, debugging

I have a problem debugging the app in Android Studio 1.4.

A typical debug aspect is when, debugging on a physical device, I purposedly switch to other
apps and then I come back to my app to check if the current Activity has some
"null" variables that prevent activity from properly recharging.
I usually set some breakpoint at the beginning of the (onResume) method.

The problem is: when I run the app the first time, the breakpoint is normally taken.
When I switch to other apps and then return to the debugging app, 
Android Studio doesn't catch the breakpoint, so I cannot debug what's wrong.

The same thing seemed to work properly in Eclipse.

Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your process is killed then the debugger is no longer attached.

You can attach a new debugger at any point

- do this just after you finish using the last app and before you open your app

It will give you a list of processes and you have to select which process to attach the debugger to.
Usually the process name includes a prefix of your package name.

https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/fast-android-debugging-with-intellij

[image]